# When PuTTY's window is closed the sshd session may not go away

Tags: ssh, putty

This is a strange one. I asked a colleague and he was also surprised by it.

We have a shell script that does whatever some such `say_hello.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Please enter your name: "
read uname
echo "Hello, ${uname}."
```

So now if we:

1. Open a new PuTTY session and authenticate (say `user1`).
2. Run the script (leave it at the prompt).
3. Right click the PuTTY title bar and select **`Duplicate Session`**.
   Authenticate again as `user1`.
4. Close first PuTTY window (opened at 1).

Look for the shell script (e.g. in the second window): `ps -ef|grep "[s]ay_hello"`
I was ***very*** surprised to see that the script - and the whole login-shell, actually - was still around.
I'd note that this behaviour is not repeated if in step 3 you select **`New Session...`** instead.

Is this a hidden documented feature of PuTTY that i missed?

**Edit:** see my answer below.

Comment: It's not a ***bug***, it's a ***feature***!

Comment: Ok, I see what you are describing now.  It is a bit weird.  I bumped my server up to DEBUG3 and I am not seeing any obvious differences on the server side in how the sessions are created.

Comment: @Opher you should post your findings as an answer instead of editing it into your question, as it actually answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it's a semi-bug I did miss. see http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/dup-sessions-dont-close.html.
I've written to PuTTY's developers and @Jacob has commented to me they were unaware it still persisted.